# SOAP WebService on Jetty howto

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jetty, jax-ws

Hello i am a bit confused by soap and jax-ws and also jetty,

i have created a WebService which soon should be capable of  SOAP (from some tutorial):

```
@WebService( endpointInterface="soap.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld
{
   public String hallo( String wer )
   {
      return "Hallo " + wer;
   }
}
```

And i got a jetty server:

```
Server server = new Server(8080); //runs on 127.0.0.1:8080   
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
.... //some servlets
server.start();
server.join();
```

Now how can i host my (SOAP)WebService on the JettyServer?